# Emulation of 5-7th gen consoles w/o a GamePad?

Tags: controllers, emulation, keyboard, mouse

If I'm emulating 5-7th gen consoles(i.e. Gamecube, N64, PS2, and Wii, mainly), and am not using a gamepad, is it feasible to actually play without it?

If it is, what sort of controls would you say are best? Entirely keyboard? Use mouse for analog? Something else(using keyboard and mouse)?

Thanks for whatever help you can offer.

EDIT: Don't bother telling me to get a gamepad. I have on but sometimes I can't take it w/ me.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 8.1 x64

Comment: Then I would certainly recommend getting a USB controller to help you with your emulation. I recommend The Microsoft one for its compatibility and build quality as men and Robotnik mention in the comments in my answer. your experience will certainly be an improvement over struggling with a keyboard.

Comment: I don't think you're reading the actual question....

Comment: Well there is no accurate way of playing a game with analog controls using digital input (keypresses). Like I said even with a mouse you wont get by on every game. The mouses analog accuracy will also be limited. Is this a laptop? Does it have a full numpad as it could be used to represent 8 directions on an analog stick.

Comment: Yeah there's a numpad. Maybe I could do the 8 directions.

Comment: Give it a go. I have used the numpad before and although it might be a little weird at the start you can get used to it.

Comment: Are you suggesting to use the NumPad as the main analog stick(usually left)? Are you suggesting I should use the mouse as the other stick, or just assign some other keys?

Comment: This is something you will need to experiment with and also depends on the game to a certain extent. The numpad is nice because all the keys are laid out square and its easy to move you fingers between them. You can use the same principle on the other side of the keyboard but its not as nice as the keys do not line up as well. If the mouse works well with the game and you do not need many other keys then try using it and the numpad. You may find you need more buttons on some games with this method though. Given that the left stick on a game is generally for strafing you might to use wsad.

Comment: This may be a stupid question but I've never been able to figure it out. When mapping something to the NumPad, do I or do I not use NumLock?

Comment: Not a silly question. What numlock does is give the keys 2 sets of functions. Think of one set being the numbers and the other being a directional pad. You can probably bind your keys to either.

Comment: Yeah I know what numlock does I was wondering if, if numlock is on, if the number keys on top of the keyboard will also have the function, or, if they're off, if the arrow keys would, or if the other functions(Home, End, etc.) would interfere with gameplay.

Comment: That may depend on how each emulator handles the key presses. If you are in an emulator none of the keys should kick off anything in the background if that's what you mean. From memory I believe my key bindings used to come up as numpad_pageup etc which would imply I was using the non numerical keyset.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the game. You will have trouble with anything requiring accurate use of analog sticks. The mouse will not always help because dual analog stick games exist on some of these platforms.

Ideally you would want to get something like a USB 360 controller.

Comment: A lot of third party controllers pretend to be Xbox 360 controllers because Windows has native support for the 'X-input' style device (not surprising, Microsoft own both Windows and Xbox). You can also find third-party drivers like MotioninJoy for PS3 controllers which do the same thing - emulate Xbox 360.

Comment: Indeed. It is both for the decent build quality and great support that I recommend the Xbox 360 controller. In my experience the only trouble I have had with them is using the wireless ones on Mac OS (Hence my question on which OS the OP is using). I assume Windows but you never know. The wireless problem above coupled with the fact that the receiver is hard to get hold of / expensive is also why I recommend the USB version